# $projection vs $elemMatch

Tags: mongodb

What is the functional difference between:

`db.docs.find({ 'a.b': 'c' }, { 'a.$': 1 })`

and

`db.docs.find({ 'a.b': 'c' }, { 'a': { $elemMatch: { b: 'c' } } })`

Is $elemMatch redundant? How would indexes change?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The difference in projection usage is somewhat subtle. In your example usage, these should be equivalent queries (in terms of index usage) but the `$elemMatch` example unnecessarily repeats the query criteria. The `$` projection would be a more sensible choice for this example.

An essential difference noted in the documentation is the [array field limitation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#array-field-limitation) for `$` projections:

> Since only one array field can appear in the query document, if the array contains documents, to specify criteria on multiple fields of these documents, use the $elemMatch operator.

Some further notes on the differences in the projection operators below ...

#### The [positional (`$`) projection operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/):

- limits the contents of an array field that is included in the query results to contain the first element that matches the query document.
- requires that the matching array field is included in the query criteria
- can only be used if a single array field appears in the query criteria
- can only be used once in a projection

#### The [`$elemMatch` projection operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#array-field-limitation)

- limits the contents of an array field that is included in the query results to contain only the first array element **that matches the $elemMatch condition**.
- does not require the matching array to be in the query criteria
- can be used to match multiple conditions for array elements that are embedded documents

#### The [`$elemMatch` query operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/)

Note that there is also an `$elemMatch` query operator which performs similar matching, but in the query rather than the results projection. It's not uncommon to see this used in combination with a `$` projection.

Borrowing an [example from the docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#array-field-limitation) where you might use both:

```
db.students.find(
    // use $elemMatch query operator to match multiple criteria in the grades array
    { grades: {
        $elemMatch: {
            mean:  { $gt: 70 },
            grade: { $gt: 90 }
        }
    }},

    // use $ projection to get the first matching item in the "grades" array
    { "grades.$": 1 }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use $elemMatch alone, in find projection,

$elemMatch will not filter documents (conditions not applied)

Suppose, 'students' contains the following documents

```
{ "_id" : 1, "semester" : 1, "grades" : [ 70, 87, 90 ] }
{ "_id" : 2, "semester" : 1, "grades" : [ 90, 88, 92 ] }
{ "_id" : 3, "semester" : 1, "grades" : [ 85, 100, 90 ] }
{ "_id" : 4, "semester" : 2, "grades" : [ 79, 85, 80 ] }
{ "_id" : 5, "semester" : 2, "grades" : [ 88, 88, 92 ] }
{ "_id" : 6, "semester" : 2, "grades" : [ 95, 90, 96 ] }
{
    "_id" : 7,
    "semester" : 3,
    "grades" : [
        {
            "grade" : 80,
            "mean" : 75,
            "std" : 8
        },
        {
            "grade" : 85,
            "mean" : 90,
            "std" : 5
        },
        {
            "grade" : 90,
            "mean" : 85,
            "std" : 3
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : 8,
    "semester" : 3,
    "grades" : [
        {
            "grade" : 92,
            "mean" : 88,
            "std" : 8
        },
        {
            "grade" : 78,
            "mean" : 90,
            "std" : 5
        },
        {
            "grade" : 88,
            "mean" : 85,
            "std" : 3
        }
    ]
}
```

the below query will return all the documents in collection,

```
db.students.find({},{ grades: { $elemMatch: { mean: 90 } } }  ).pretty()
```

where as, below query returns only the matching records

```
db.students.find({"grades.mean":90},{"grades.$":1}).pretty()
```

i hope Indexes do not make any difference in either queries

Comment: I think you are confusing projection with queries :). For a fair comparison, you need to have a query in both of your find examples.

Comment: May be:( , 
if $elemMatch(projection) doesnt filter documents, and is only used to return first matching element, then why to use $elemMatch with nested queries, we can simply use $ projection

Comment: The $elemMatch projection "can be used to match multiple conditions for array elements that are embedded documents" as @Stennie pointed out in his answer. To be honest I wish the projection docs would provide a more direct comparison as Stennie outlined.

Comment: I answered with a bit more elaboration on the differences. Typically you probably want to use a `$` projection, but there are some use cases where `$elemMatch` is more appropriate (for example, matching multiple conditions for the array elements). Also note that projection is done at the *document* level when results are returned. With your first example with `$elemMatch` on all documents, in the results you get will see either the `_id` plus the first matching `grades` array element, or `_id` alone (since there is no matching element to project).

Comment: @paulkon: Agreed, the docs should include this sort of direct comparison. I'll submit a suggestion for same :).