# How to filter array in a mongodb query

Tags: mongodb

In mongodb, I have a collection that contains a single document that looks like the following:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5552b7fd9e8c7572e36e39df"), 
    "StackSummaries" : [
        {
            "StackId" : "arn:aws:cloudformation:ap-southeast-2:406119630047:stack/XXXX-30fb22a-285-439ee279-c7c8d36/4ebd8770-f8f4-11e4-bf36-503f2370240f", 
            "TemplateDescription" : "XXXX", 
            "StackStatusReason" : "", 
            "CreationTime" : "2015-05-12T22:14:50.535Z", 
            "StackName" : "XXXX", 
            "StackStatus" : "CREATE_COMPLETE"
        }, 
        {
            "TemplateDescription" : "XXXX", 
            "StackStatusReason" : "", 
            "CreationTime" : "2015-05-11T04:02:05.543Z", 
            "StackName" : "XXXX", 
            "StackStatus" : "DELETE_COMPLETE", 
            "StackId" : "arn:aws:cloudformation:ap-southeast-2:406119630047:stack/XXXXX/7c8d04e0-f792-11e4-bb12-506726f15f9a"
        },
        { ... },
        { many others }
    ]
}
```

ie the imported results of the **aws cli** command `aws cloudformation
list-stacks`

I'm trying to find the items of the `StackSummaries` array that have a `StackStatus` of `CREATE_COMPLETE` or `UPDATE_COMPLETE`. After much experimenting and reading other SO posts I arrived at the following:

```
db.cf_list_stacks.aggregate( {$match: {"StackSummaries.StackStatus": "CREATE_COMPLETE"}})
```

However this still returns the whole document (and I haven't even worried about UPDATE_COMPLETE).

I'm coming from an SQL background and struggling with simple queries like this. Any ideas on how to get the information I'm looking for?

SO posts I've looked at:

- [MongoDB query with elemMatch for nested array data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20525754/mongodb-query-with-elemmatch-for-nested-array-data)
- [MongoDB: multiple $elemMatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25014699/mongodb-multiple-elemmatch)
- [$projection vs $elemMatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21519185/projection-vs-elemmatch)
- [Make $elemMatch (projection) return all objects that match criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19696282/make-elemmatch-projection-return-all-objects-that-match-criteria)

**Update**

Notes on things I learned while understanding this topic:

- **aggregate()** is just a *pipeline* (like a Unix shell pipeline) where each $ operator is just another step. And like shell pipelines they can look complex, but you just build them up step by step until you get the results you want
- Mongo has a great webinar: [Exploring the Aggregation Framework](https://www.mongodb.com/webinar/exploring-the-aggregation-framework?jmp=docs&_ga=1.109596165.1669961256.1431482501)
- [RoboMongo](http://robomongo.org/) is a good tool (GPL3) for working with Mongo data and queries

Comment: Do you only what sub-document that match the given criteria?  What is the expected output in your case?

Comment: Hi @Michael there's only one document in the collection, so I want to "transform" the document so that the StackSummaries array only contains elements that have a StackStatus of CREATE_COMPLETE or UPDATE_COMPLETE. Probably the other answers will help me, I've just woken up and yet to understand them fully.

Answer (score 4):

If you only want the object inside the StackSummaries array, you should use the `$unwind` clause to expand the array, filter the documents you want and then project only the parts of the document that you actually want.

The query would look something like this:

```
db.cf_list_stacks.aggregate([
    { '$unwind' : '$StackSummaries' },
    { '$match' : { 'StackSummaries.StackStatus' : 'CREATE_COMPLETE' } },
    { '$project' : { 
         'TemplateDescription' : '$StackSummaries.TemplateDescription',
         'StackStatusReason' : '$StackSummaries.StackStatusReason',
         ...
    } }
])
```

Useful links:

- [Aggregation pipeline documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/)
- [`$unwind` Documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/)
- [`$project` Documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/)

Comment: Thanks @SanSS and Chridam for your great answers, I really appreciate it. I've upvoted both, it will take me a while to understand the answers before I can vote on a "correct" answer (though they're probably both correct).

Answer (score 3):

With MongoDB 3.4 and newer, you can leverage the **[`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/#pipe._S_addFields)** and **[`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/#exp._S_filter)** operators with the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/) to get the desired result.

Consider running the following pipeline:

```
db.cf_list_stacks.aggregate([
    {
        "$addFields": {
            "StackSummaries": {
                "$filter": {
                    "input": "$StackSummaries",
                    "as": "el":
                    "cond": {
                        "$in": [ 
                            "$$el.StackStatus", 
                            ["CREATE_COMPLETE", "UPDATE_COMPLETE"] 
                        ] 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

---

For MongoDB 3.2

```
db.cf_list_stacks.aggregate([
    {
        "$project": {
            "StackSummaries": {
                "$filter": {
                    "input": "$StackSummaries",
                    "as": "el":
                    "cond": {
                        "$or": [
                            { "$eq": ["$$el.StackStatus", "CREATE_COMPLETE"] },
                            { "$eq": ["$$el.StackStatus", "UPDATE_COMPLETE"] }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

---

For MongoDB 3.0 and below

```
db.cf_list_stacks.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$StackSummaries" },
    {
        "$match": {            
            "StackSummaries.StackStatus": {
                "$in": ["CREATE_COMPLETE", "UPDATE_COMPLETE"]
            }
        }        
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "StackSummaries": {
                "$addToSet": "$StackSummaries"
            }
        }
    }
])
```

The above pipeline has the [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind) operator which deconstructs the `StackSummaries` array field from the input documents to output a document for each element. Each output document replaces the array with an element value.

A further filtering is required after the [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind) to get only the documents that pass the given criteria thus a second [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match) operator pipeline stage follows.

In order to get the original array field after doing the [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind) bit, you would need to group the documents using the [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) operator and within the group you can then use the [**`$addToSet`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet) array operator to then push the elements into the array.

---

Based on the criteria that you are trying to find the items of the `StackSummaries` array that have a `StackStatus` of `CREATE_COMPLETE` **OR** `UPDATE_COMPLETE`, you could use [**`$elemMatch` projection**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) but this won't work with the [**`$in`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator as required to get the document with `StackStatus` of `CREATE_COMPLETE` **OR** `UPDATE_COMPLETE` at this time. There is a **[JIRA](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-14203)** issue for this:

```
db.cf_list_stacks.find(
    {
        "StackSummaries.StackStatus": {
            "$in": ["CREATE_COMPLETE", "UPDATE_COMPLETE"]
        }
    }, 
    {
        "StackSummaries": {
            "$elemMatch": {
                "StackStatus": {
                    "$in": ["CREATE_COMPLETE", "UPDATE_COMPLETE"]
                }
            }            
        }    
    })
```

This will only give you documents where the `StackStatus` has the `"CREATE_COMPLETE"` value.

Comment: Thanks SanSS and @Chridam for your great answers, I really appreciate it. I've upvoted both, it will take me a while to understand the answers before I can vote on a "correct" answer (though they're probably both correct).

Comment: @chridam I think there is an extra `$match` operation in your aggregation pipeline. She explicitly says that the collection has a single document, so the first `$match` of your aggregation won't save any actual work.